# How to automate starting a multiuser screen session with adding acl to another user?

Tags: linux, automation, gnu-screen

I often start a screen session, issue a ":multiuser on" command and then ":acladd someuser".

Is there some way to get with a single shell command a screen session to start with these two commands automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a custom screen config file with `screen -c file`. For example:

```
echo "multiuser on" >> multiscreen.conf
echo "acladd someuser" >> multiscreen.conf
alias multiscreen='screen -c multiscreen.conf' # bash syntax for alias
multiscreen
```

Answer (score 0):

Add them to your `~/.screenrc` file (without the colons). See the screen man page and the example files it refers to (possibly at `/usr/share/doc/screen/examples`).

Comment: hmm.. I need it as an optional thing, not for all screen sessions. using the .screenrc would probably apply all the time, wouldn't it?